# How to display a calculated value and a table when a button is clicked?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm tyring to display a "result table"(showing the area value and calculated time) only after a user inputs both width and height value and presse the button.

What I attempted was display input values on a sheet so the inputs are correctly passed to the function `setParam()`.

My problems are

1. How to display a table only after a button is pressed.
2. How to set a calculated are value returned from a function to the web application.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="area">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Area</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>width</td>
            <td><input id="width" type="number" ></input></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>height</td>
            <td><input id="height" type="number"></input></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" onclick="calculateArea()" id="" value="Calcuate This!">
    </div>

<div id="createdTable"></div>

    <script>
      function calculateArea() {
        const width = document.getElementById('width').value;
        const height = document.getElementById('height').value;
        google.script.run.setParam(width, height);

        var htmlTable = '<table id="xxx" border=1>' +
                          '<thead>' +
                            '<tr> +
                              '<th>Result</th> +
                            '</tr>' +
                          '</thead>' +
                          '<tbody>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                              '<td>Area</td>' +
                              '<td><input value=""><?=getArea();?></input></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                              '<td>Calculation Time</td>' +
                              '<td><input value=""></input></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                          '</tbody>' +
                        '</table>';

        document.getElementById("createdTable").innerHTML = htmlTable;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
let width = 0;
let height = 0;
let area = 0;
let time = 0;

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function setParam(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=0");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

  ws.getRange(1,1).setValue(width);
  ws.getRange(2,1).setValue(height);
}

function getArea() {
  area = width * height;
  return area;
}

function getTime() {
  return time;
}
```

Comment: With getValues() and getValue()

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the problem with the code included in the question? Did you write it?

Comment: @Cooper Is it approprite to call getArea() instead of getValue()? I thought because width and height value are set in setParam(), I could just simply use getArea()...

Comment: @Rubén I edited the post so I hope it clarifies the problems.

Comment: @ikokai You can call any of the methods in [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: @Cooper Thank you. I try to research more to do it.

Comment: Questions on this site should be specific, meaning only one question per post. Despite the edits, it's still missing a description of the problems of the code included. If you don't understand the code included, you should start by learning the pretty basics of JavaScript and Google Apps Script. If you are able to deploy the web app, show the the web browser console logs and the Google Apps Script execution logs.